# SQL Server 2005 Accessing a FileUpload control in code-behind

Tags: c#, .net

I want to access a FileUpload control in code-behind. Here is my code:
    FileUpload file = (FileUpload)this.FindControl("FleUpload");

and the control is resided in a FormView. but "file" has a null value after I run the project. 
what should I do to access the FileUpload control in the formview ?

help please

Comment: please correct the tag for this question. are you using .net, java? web forms, Win forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this code :

```
if(FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit){
  FileUpload f = (FileUpload) FormView1.FindControl("FleUpload");
  .... then rest of code
}
```

and it worked.